# How can an international MRO apply for FAA approval?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, faa-approval

I own a small [maintenance, repair, and operations (MRO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance,_repair,_and_operations) shop in Indonesia. We are having trouble with our customers that required us to obtain FAA approval in order to get order from them.

I already tried to ask the Indonesian regulator to help us to obtain FAA approval, but no luck. FAA requires an MRO to maintain at least one N-registered aircraft, and we don't have any in here.

Does anyone have same experience? And how can we proceed?

Answer (score 1):

[These](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/repair/become/forms/) *14 CFR Part 145 Forms* might be the forms you are looking for however there may be other forms for applying from overseas.

[This](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/repair/) site (FAA Aircraft Repair Stations Homepage) has some good links and [here](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/repair/become/preapplication/) are the pre application regulations you need to comply with.

[Here](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=d4441a9abc28fb63c4aead954102f6d7&node=14:3.0.1.2.19&rgn=div5) is the letter of the law of the FAA regulations (Starts at *Title 14 Section 145.1*).

I am no lawyer and cant really comment on this but I have no idea how FAA regulations work outside of the country and how/what foreign entities must comply with. I would advise contacting a local lawyer as well as a US lawyer about this.

Comment: If you could supply some relevant search terms in case the FAA or EFCR web sites get rearranged, that would make this answer much more useful in the long term.

Comment: Are there any special lawyer or agency that specialize in this field? Which one?

Comment: You can try contacting the FAA directly (not quite sure how to do that), as for a lawyer I would look for someone who has some experience in the aviation world. Maybe someone who worked for a firm that has handled an airline or maintenance facility already.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply for foreign FAA Repair station certificate under PART145 to your nearest Foreign FASDO (Flight Standards District filed office) . There are several steps one must take for compliance as per regulations including training.